# openni_launch - ROS Fuerte

Tags: rviz, openni-launch, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

Since ROS Fuerte openni_camera and openni_launch are two different packages.

When I like to use the Camera topic in rviz, which node do I have to start?

Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67255/openni_launch---ros-fuerte/) by [JaRu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3620/jaru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2013-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Right now, if you are working on fuerte you only have to roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch this will launch all the nodes related to the kinect. If everything is correct you should se the topics with a rostopic list.

/camera/rgb/camera_info
/camera/rgb/image_raw
... A lot more.

You can be sure you are receiving info by typing in the terminal rostopic echo /camera/rgb/image_raw a lot of numbers will full your screen in a few secs.

Open Rviz add a display for the topic you want to display. And you should see the data if everything is correct.

---

Originally posted by [agonzamart](https://answers.ros.org/users/3277/agonzamart/) with karma: 88 on 2013-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JaRu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3620/jaru/) on 2013-07-13**:
the rostopic echo works, but when I add the Camera display in rviz --> Image: no image received

**Comment by [agonzamart](https://answers.ros.org/users/3277/agonzamart/) on 2013-07-13**:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes You can see the displays here, to see what topic to read. The one you need is the image one. Then you need to clic on the new display on the left spread it and choose the topic you have to read. http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch, check tutorials